# Pandas issue extracting hyperlinks from excel

Tags: python, json, pandas, scripting

The goal of this Python script would be to find the corresponding URL for whichever state that was input. I keep getting these errors during the "Lookup" portion of the script. The name of the input is 'state'. The code works when the url is hard coded but I keep getting the below error with the lookup value.

Please see the below code and result

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1', dtype=str)
df.to_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.csv.xlsx')

df['URL'] = df['URL'].astype('|S80')
stateurl =(df[df['State']==state]['URL'])
print(stateurl)
```

Print results:

```
8    b'https://incomplete.url/tes...
Name: URL, dtype: object
```

Whenever I run with my webcrawler (which runs with a hardcoded url), the code throws an error in selenium, its unable to open an "invalid URL"

Comment: Try ```stateurl =df[df['State']==state]['URL'].iloc[0]```

Comment: Or alternatively `stateurl = df[df['State']==state]['URL'].values[0]`

Comment: Those worked perfectly. I knew it would be something very minor. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stateurl =df[df['State']==state]['URL'].iloc[0]
```

Suraj Motaparthy got the syntax I was looking for